# The compiler is unhappy about my generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

It always complains with:

```
The method add(Matrix<T>) in the type List<Matrix<T>> is not applicable for the arguments (Matrix<String>)
```

In the line of the Extractor class:

```
matrixList.add(new Matrix<String>(attributes));
```

It seems there is a problem in defining my generics in these 3 classes. Is there an easy way to fix that? Tried different ways and can't figure it out.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Extractor<String> extractor = new Extractor<>();
        extractor.extract();
    }
}

class Extractor<T> {

    private List<Matrix<T>> matrixList;

    public Extractor() {
        this.matrixList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void extract() {
        List<Attribute<String>> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

        attributes.add(new Attribute<String>("Test 1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute<String>("Test 2"));

       // !!!! The compiler is complaining here!
        matrixList.add(new Matrix<String>(attributes));
    }

    public List<Matrix<T>> getList() {
        return matrixList;
    }
}

class Matrix<T> {

    private List<Attribute<T>> attributes;

    public Matrix(List<Attribute<T>> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public List<Attribute<T>> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
}

class Attribute<T> {
    private T attribute;
    public Attribute(T attr) {
        attribute = attr;
    }

    public T getAttr() {
        return attribute;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code simply does not make sense. You are making `Extractor` etc generic, which means you want it to work for different types.

However, in `Extractor.extract()` method, you are specifically creating a `Matrix` of `String` and put it into your `List<Matrix<T>> matrixList`.

If your code only works for String, then you shouldn't make it generic.  Just make `List<Matrix<String>> matrixList`.

Give it a thought: if now you are creating a `Extractor<Integer> intExtractor`, and calling `intExtractor.extract()`, how can it be reasonable for your code to work?

Or, to further polish your design, make it:

```
interface Extractor<T> {
    public List<Matrix<T>> extract();
}

class DummyStringMatrixExtractor implements Extractor<String> {

    // useless now, can be put in extract()
    private List<Matrix<T>> matrixList;

    public Extractor() {
        this.matrixList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Matrix<String>> extract() {
        List<Attribute<String>> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

        attributes.add(new Attribute<String>("Test 1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute<String>("Test 2"));

        matrixList.add(new Matrix<String>(attributes));

        return matrixList;
    }

    // useless now
    public List<Matrix<T>> getList() {
        return matrixList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely worded Adrian

Comment: Of course not only works with String. In this Extractor it has to work with String, and I have other Extractors (inherit from an abstract extractor), which works with other types of Object. And that's why I want to use T type.

Comment: @user697911 that's why I said it does not make sense: "this Extractor" has to work with string, that means it is *NOT* the generic Extractor that works for different type.  Please check again my suggested design revision to make sure you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Adrian, I have something very similar to yours, an but can't get it to work. I also have an Interface for the abstract Extractor. The key may be this line "class DummyStringMatrixExtractor implements Extractor<String> ". My concrete extractors should NOT be generics. My whole code is a little more complex and I will see whether I can get it to work follow your thought.

Comment: @user697911 _"**interface** for the **abstract** Extractor"_ ?! better make sure you use proper terminologies so people are not going to misunderstand what you mean.  Don't understand what your "concrete extractors" means: if it is a specialized extractor that is going to produce Matrix of a specific type, then it shouldn't be generic

Comment: Yes. I have an interface, and an abstract extractor to implement the interface, and several concrete extractors to sublclass from the abstract extractor. All these currently are type of T, due to the very bottom Attribute<T>. I need to get rid of type T from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put `Matrix<String>` to list of  `Matrix<T>` (`T` may be any type here). If the `Extractor` works only with Matrix of type String, remove the type argument from there and set `matrixList` type to  `List<Matrix<String>>`.

Comment: I don't think so. T maybe String or the other type. In this class, he can use Matrix<T>  for Matrix<String>  here and he can use Matrix<T> for any type in somewhere.

Comment: @kimdung it is totally wrong.  Do you really understand what Generics is trying to solve?

Comment: @kimdung In this case the extract method should return `Matrix<String>` instead of adding it to private field with type `T`.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't review his code carefully. His Extractor<T> violates what Generics is doing.

Comment: The point of T is due to my Attribute<T>, because Attribute has to work with different types, and there could be multiple types of extractors with multiple types of T, which originate from the Attribute<T>. In my code, Extractor is just one type of T. There are other Extractor, in which T won't be String.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use `matrixList.add((Matrix<T>) new Matrix<String>(attributes));` instead.

The code imposes a very common casting problem of generics.

The approach presented in the code `matrixList.add(new Matrix<String>(attributes))` implies that you want to add a **Matrix** element to container **matrixList** which is defined to contain generic template type.

You may find simpler illustrations of such hurdles in the documentation [over here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)

Comment: It actually works with a warning, unchecked cast. Is this good practice here? To cast a concrete type to a generic type. If this works, probably it's the easiest to solve my hurdle.

Comment: it's just a check for an unchecked cast. You may suppress unchecked warnings via @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). It's completely safe and of course not a bad practice in this context.